# Is there any way to find extension for password protected ms word, ms excel and ms power point using tika-core

Tags: mime-types, apache-tika

using org.apache.tika:tika-core:1.24 to find the Mimetype. but for Password protected file such as word, excel and powerpoint, it returns mime type `x-tika-msoffice` but no exentions. It works for password protected pdf file

```
findMimeType() {
TikaConfig config = TikaConfig.getDefaultConfig();

        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        metadata.set(Metadata.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, fileName);
        MediaType mediaType = config.getDetector().detect(TikaInputStream.get(inputStream), metadata);

        return config.getMimeRepository().forName(mediaType.toString());
}
```

using tika core expecting to get password proteced file extension

Comment: Do you have the password for the files?